# relief of Switzerland from a tiff-file

Tags: r, gis, raster

I would like an official source for drawing the relief over a map of Switzerland. On one of the pages of swisstopo I found following file:
https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe-pk1000.noscale/swiss-map-raster1000_2022_1000/swiss-map-raster1000_2022_1000_kgrel_50_2056.tif

Now, how is it possible to choose the different layers of this tiff-File escpacially the relief?

If I try

```
relief <- raster(swiss-map-raster1000_2022_1000_krel_50_2056.tif")
plot(relief)`
```

I only see a green map, while having a look to the original tiff-file shows a nice map of Switzerland.

Comment: All green, or all one value, suggests the one you chose was a mask, not the multiple valued relief/elevation map you were looking for.

Comment: It's just a georeferenced grayscale map image, sounds like you are after something provided though https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/geodata/height.html instead.

Comment: Thanks for that hint: I changed my question and posted it as a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a RGB (Red, Green, Blue) image, but because all channels have the same value, the colors are all grays

You can open the file like this:

```
library(terra)

# using vsicurl to avoid downloading for this example; 
# but if you are going to use you should download it first 
f <- "/vsicurl/https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe-pk1000.noscale/swiss-map-raster1000_2022_1000/swiss-map-raster1000_2022_1000_kgrel_50_2056.tif"

x <- rast(f)
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10000, 14800, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 50, 50  (x, y)
#extent      : 2317000, 3057000, 913000, 1413000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : CH1903+ / LV95 (EPSG:2056) 
#source      : swiss-map-raster1000_2022_1000_kgrel_50_2056.tif 
#colors RGB  : 1, 2, 3 
#names       : swiss-map-~0_2056_1; , swiss-map-~0_2056_2; , swiss-map-~0_2056_3;
```

And plot it like this

```
plot(f)
```

[image]
.

You can zoom in with `zoom(x)` and clicking twice on the map to create a box. To get, e.g.,

[image]

Comment: Thanks, nice to see, how I can use this tiff-file! Unfortunately I try to create (only) a map with the relief of Switzerland and therefore (obviously) the tiff-file is not appropriate - I precised my question now.

Comment: You changed it into a entirely different question. I would suggest reverting to your original question and then asking a new one.